# Resizing svg in a panel in java

Tags: java, resize, svg, batik

I have a svg file in a panel and it is displayed. The problem occurs when i try to change the size of it (svg). I tried setSize, setPreferredSize  and resize but none work. I noticed that when i try to resize it resizes but then goes back to it's previous size. Can someone help me, please?

```
svg.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(700,700));
svg.setSize(new Dimension(700,700));
this.add(svg, BorderLayout.NORTH);
this.setSize(1000, 1000);
```

My class extends JPanel. I'm using batik.

Comment: please show what layout you are using in your [sscce](http://sscce.org/).

Comment: i used:
BorderLayout b=new BorderLayout();
this.setLayout(b);
but i found a solution to this problem. anyway, thanks for the will to help :D

Comment: If you think it will help others, its [OK](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/17463/should-i-ask-a-question-i-know-the-answer-to) to answer your own question. More in the [faq].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I added svg to JSVGScrollPane. Now it works fine, resizes well and i have scrollbars when svg is bigger. It took me day and a half of experimenting with JPanels, JScrollPanes, but this is the best solution. [: